# Graphical diff viewer between local and repo file

Tags: diff, phpstorm, file-comparison

Here is my use case.
I want to compare a local file i am working on with a repo file using a diff viewer.
For example

```
file 1 : /path-to-local-file-in-my-computer
file 2 : http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-load.php
```

Is there any program that can compare a file in my machine and a repo file in the internet??
I want to edit, revert changes line by line comparing to files. Some thing like phpstorm diff viewer?

Answer (score 2):

If the local file is *not* a check-out of the online repository, it think your only option will be to download the online repository, select both your 'own' version and the downloaded version and compare them with the compare function of PhpStorm (ctrl+D or cmd+D on OS X)

PhpStorm also allows you to compare two directories (including their subdirectories). Here's a recent blog post describing this feature:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/02/comparing-files-and-folders-within-your-ide/

Answer (score 1):

If you intend only to edit the file on your computer, ECMerge (our tool) can do that. Just open a 2-way merge, select the local file in left pane and set is as output, the web file in the right pane. Select what is OK (differences are highlighted and can be selected, then further modified in the result pane). Saving will update your left file on disk, and you can refresh to continue.